# Django REST Updateview with PUT POST - skip updated values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Trying to update a field with REST, I've tried this with postgresql database and it skip the updated data, it get in the save() of the model but without the updated **opt** value

**views**

```
class LinkUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): #UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = models.mymode.objects.all()
```

**serializer**

```
  class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
         pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
         opt =  serializers.IntegerField(required=True) 



 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.opt = validated_data.get('OPT', instance.opt)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

it appear that the instance.opt isn't passed to the instance.save().
If I replace:

```
 instance.opt = validated_data.get('OPT', instance.opt)
```

with a fixed value:

```
instance.opt = validated_data.get('OPT', 11)
```

it works, what am I missing?

Comment: and what about `instance.opt = validated_data.get('opt', instance.opt)` ?

Comment: thanks I've missed it!